# Scikit-learn pipeline : possibility of rows aggregation (pandas groupby)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, pipeline

I wish to run all preprocessing and model optimisation tasks in a single pipeline with the following steps :

1. onehot encoding
2. SVD dimension reduction
3. aggregation (pandas groupby)
4. Random Forest modelisation

my input variables are :

- X_train with 349 rows, which will become 338 rows after step3 (aggregation)
- y_train with 338 rows

I get the error "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples."

It's because sklearn doesn't allow a difference of rows number between X_train and y_train.

**Do you know another method, if possible, to have an aggregation in a pipeline ?**

here is my code :

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# does nothing, but is here to collect numerical columns
class nothing(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):       

        return self

    def transform(self, X):          

        return X


class Aggregator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        X = X.rename(columns = {0 :'InvoiceNo', 1 : 'amount', 2:'Quantity', 
                                3:'UnitPrice',4:'CustomerID' })
        X['InvoiceNo'] =  X['InvoiceNo'].astype('int')
        X['Quantity'] = X['Quantity'].astype('float64')
        X['UnitPrice'] = X['UnitPrice'].astype('float64')
        aggregations = dict()
        for col in range(5, X.shape[1]-1) :
            aggregations[col] = 'max'

        aggregations.update({ 'CustomerID' : 'first',
                            'amount' : "sum",'Quantity' : 'mean', 'UnitPrice' : 'mean'})

        # aggregating all basket lines
        result = X.groupby('InvoiceNo').agg(aggregations)

        # add number of lines in the basket
        result['lines_nb'] = X.groupby('InvoiceNo').size()
        return result

 numeric_features = ['InvoiceNo','amount', 'Quantity', 'UnitPrice', 
                           'CustomerID']
 numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('nothing', nothing())])

 categorical_features = ['StockCode', 'Country']   

 preprocessor =  ColumnTransformer(
        [
        # 'num' transformer does nothing, but is here to  
        # collect numerical columns
        ('num', numeric_transformer ,numeric_features ),
        ('cat', Pipeline([
            ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
            ('best', TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)),
         ]), categorical_features)        
          ]
          )           

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
                      ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('aggregator', Aggregator()),
                      ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=400, 
                        max_features='auto',                                         
                        class_weight=class_weights)),
                     ])

X_train_transformed = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [349, 338]
```

more detail to answer to @desertnaut comment :

example :

**X_train** contains 4 rows :
customer_num : 1    article_ref : 1   money : 10$
customer_num : 1    article_ref : 2   money : 15$
customer_num : 2    article_ref : 5   money : 5$
customer_num : 3    article_ref : 4   money : 11$

I aggregate the 4 rows with pandas groupby=cucstomer_num, the resulting dataframe , **X_train_transformed** , has 3 rows, one per customer

**y_train** has 3 rows, containing the group (label to predict) for customer_num 1, customer_num 2 et customer_num 3.

The standard method is :

pipeline 1 :  transform X_train (4 rows)  to X_train_transformed (3 rows)
pipeline 2  : fit a model to (X_train_transformed (3 rows), y_train(3 rows))

I whish to have a single pipeline to handle pipeline 1 and pipeline 2

Comment: The equality of samples between data `X` and labels `y` is a fundamental (and elementary...) requirement (i.e. not a specific characteristic of scikit-learn); and what do you mean that `X_train` "will become 338 rows after rows"??

Comment: the [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable) library is an example for how to syn rows between the train and test datasets . I'm not sure how your x_train and y_train differ, did you mean x_train and x_test?